# Insert multiple option using multiple select bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic bootstrap multiple select like that :

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="listeFormation">
  <?php while($row = $displayFormation->fetch()){?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['form_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['form_intitule'];?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And i wanted to know how is it possible to insert in only one column (endpro_form) all the form_id that the user selected with why not a separator like : ',' or '-'.

I tried this but it's working only when i select one option.

```
$insertForm = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO ENT_PRO (entpro_form) VALUES (?)'); 
$insertForm->execute(array($_POST['listeFormation']));
```

Thanks for your help.